# Поиск пробела после слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Всем привет! подскажите пожалуйста как найти пробел после *я* или *мы*.
Нахожу пробел до *я* или *мы*, а как сделать поиск назад не знаю.

```
 \s(?=я|мы)
```

Comment: `(?<=` для соответствия и `(?<!` для несоответствия

гуглится как regexp lookbehind assertions, если еще понадобится.

Comment: насколько мне известно lookbehind в js не поддерживается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найти пробел после *я* и *мы* в JavaScript легко, [смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/6wk4z/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы поймать ***пробел(ы)*** после "**Я**" или "**Мы**":

```
/(?:я|мы)([\s]+)/gi
```

[Реальный пример](http://regex101.com/r/bR8zU6)

Чтобы просто узнать есть ли ***пробел*** после "**Я**" или "**Мы**":

```
/(?:я|мы)(?=\s)/gi
```

[Реальный пример](http://regex101.com/r/aO1fK4)

Comment: @vox, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).  

Ответ @HA3IK является исчерпывающим ввиду того, что в JavaScript не получится захватить в совпадение только пробел ввиду отсутствия поддержки `lookbehind` в регулярных выражениях.

Comment: @ReinRaus ответ @HA3IK оказался не исчерпывающим! ;-)